# R function for reformatting columns to rows indicating start and stop points

Tags: r, reformatting

I am trying to figure out a way in R to reformate my data frame so that the Veh column with 2 or more stops (Areas) are represented in their own row with Area 2 repeated as a new starting point. Being relatively new to R-- I am not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be most appreciated.

For example, id like to convert this

```
ID  Veh   Area 1    Area 2  Area 3   Area 4
1  Veh 1  Area A    Area B    NA       NA                    
2  Veh 2  Area C    NA        NA       NA                     
3  Veh 3  Area D    Area A    NA       NA                   
4  Veh 4  Area E    Area F   Area D  Area A 
5  Veh 5  Area H    Area B   Area C    NA    
6  Veh 6  Area J    Area K   Area A  Area B
```

into this:

```
ID  Veh    Start_Area  Stop_Area
1  Veh 1   Area A      Area B 
2  Veh 2   Area C      Area C
3  Veh 3   Area D      Area A 
4  Veh 4   Area E      Area F 
5  Veh 4   Area F      Area G
6  Veh 4   Area D      Area A   
7  Veh 5   Area H      Area B      
8  Veh 5   Area B      Area C  
9  Veh 6   Area J      Area K   
10 Veh 6   Area K      Area F 
11 Veh 6   Area A      Area B
```

and then count the frequency of each pair

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` to do this.  Loop over the rows with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1`) with the subset of columns i.e remove the 1st two columns (not needed), then we remove the `NA` in the row (`na.omit`), `if` the `length` of the resultant vector is 1, then create a `data.frame` with both columns as that value or `else`, remove the first and last value to create the 'Stop_Area', 'Start_Area'.  The output will be a `list`.  Then, we `rep`licate the rows of the original dataset based on the number of rows of this `list`, and the `cbind` it with the `list` `cbind`ed

```
lst1 <- apply(df1[-(1:2)], 1, function(x) {
      x1 <- na.omit(x)
 if(length(x1) == 1) data.frame(StartArea = x1, Stop_Area = x1) else 
    data.frame(StartArea = x1[-length(x1)], Stop_Area = x1[-1]) 
  })

out <- cbind(df1[1:2][rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)),
          sapply(lst1, nrow)),], do.call(rbind, lst1))
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
out
#   ID   Veh StartArea Stop_Area
#1   1 Veh 1    Area A    Area B
#2   2 Veh 2    Area C    Area C
#3   3 Veh 3    Area D    Area A
#4   4 Veh 4    Area E    Area F
#5   4 Veh 4    Area F    Area D
#6   4 Veh 4    Area D    Area A
#7   5 Veh 5    Area H    Area B
#8   5 Veh 5    Area B    Area C
#9   6 Veh 6    Area J    Area K
#10  6 Veh 6    Area K    Area A
#11  6 Veh 6    Area A    Area B
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Veh = c("Veh 1", "Veh 2", "Veh 3", "Veh 4", 
"Veh 5", "Veh 6"), Area1 = c("Area A", "Area C", "Area D", "Area E", 
"Area H", "Area J"), Area2 = c("Area B", NA, "Area A", "Area F", 
"Area B", "Area K"), Area3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Area D", "Area C", 
"Area A"), Area4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Area A", NA, "Area B")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on `tidyverse`.

### Create df target

Because `Area C` doesn't have a Stop Area clearly indicated between `Area2-3-4`, we need to replace the missing value in `Area2` with `Area1` when `Area2-3-4` are missing. Note we use `rowwise` and `c_across` to instruct our code to check row by row.

At that point you just reshape your data with `pivot_longer` and you remove all NAs by specifying `values_drop_na = TRUE`.

Last touch: you can define `StartArea` and `StopArea` for each `ID` and `Veh`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Area2 = if_else(all(is.na(c_across(c(Area2, Area3, Area4)))), Area1, Area2)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Area"), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Veh) %>% 
  summarise(StartArea = value[-length(value)],
            StopArea = value[-1],
            .groups = "drop")

df1
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#>       ID Veh   StartArea StopArea
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>   
#>  1     1 Veh 1 Area A    Area B  
#>  2     2 Veh 2 Area C    Area C  
#>  3     3 Veh 3 Area D    Area A  
#>  4     4 Veh 4 Area E    Area F  
#>  5     4 Veh 4 Area F    Area D  
#>  6     4 Veh 4 Area D    Area A  
#>  7     5 Veh 5 Area H    Area B  
#>  8     5 Veh 5 Area B    Area C  
#>  9     6 Veh 6 Area J    Area K  
#> 10     6 Veh 6 Area K    Area A  
#> 11     6 Veh 6 Area A    Area B
```

---

### Count

To count the frequency you can use `count`:

```
df1 %>% count(StartArea, StopArea)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   StartArea StopArea     n
#>   <chr>     <chr>    <int>
#> 1 Area A    Area B       2
#> 2 Area B    Area C       1
#> 3 Area C    Area C       1
#> 4 Area D    Area A       2
#> 5 Area E    Area F       1
#> 6 Area F    Area D       1
#> 7 Area H    Area B       1
#> 8 Area J    Area K       1
#> 9 Area K    Area A       1
```

If you want to count the couples of Areas that are connected and you do not care about the direction, then you need to sort each row first.

```
df2 <- df1 %>% select(StartArea,StopArea)
df2[] <- asplit(apply(df2, 1, sort), 1) # sort by row

df2 %>% count(StartArea, StopArea)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   StartArea StopArea     n
#>   <chr>     <chr>    <int>
#> 1 Area A    Area B       2
#> 2 Area A    Area D       2
#> 3 Area A    Area K       1
#> 4 Area B    Area C       1
#> 5 Area B    Area H       1
#> 6 Area C    Area C       1
#> 7 Area D    Area F       1
#> 8 Area E    Area F       1
#> 9 Area J    Area K       1
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Veh = c("Veh 1", "Veh 2", "Veh 3", "Veh 4", 
"Veh 5", "Veh 6"), Area1 = c("Area A", "Area C", "Area D", "Area E", 
"Area H", "Area J"), Area2 = c("Area B", NA, "Area A", "Area F", 
"Area B", "Area K"), Area3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Area D", "Area C", 
"Area A"), Area4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Area A", NA, "Area B")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

*data.table* solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)

melt(df1, id.vars=c("ID","Veh"))[!is.na(value)][
    ,
    if(.N == 1) .(start=value, stop=value) else
                .(start = value[-.N], stop = value[-1]),
    by=c("ID","Veh")    
]

#    ID   Veh  start   stop
# 1:  1 Veh 1 Area A Area B
# 2:  2 Veh 2 Area C Area C
# 3:  3 Veh 3 Area D Area A
# 4:  4 Veh 4 Area E Area F
# 5:  4 Veh 4 Area F Area D
# 6:  4 Veh 4 Area D Area A
# 7:  5 Veh 5 Area H Area B
# 8:  5 Veh 5 Area B Area C
# 9:  6 Veh 6 Area J Area K
#10:  6 Veh 6 Area K Area A
#11:  6 Veh 6 Area A Area B
```

Which can be extended further if you want to jump straight to counting how many of each pair:

```
melt(df1, id.vars=c("ID","Veh"))[!is.na(value)][
    ,
    if(.N == 1) .(start=value, stop=value) else
                .(start = value[-.N], stop = value[-1]),
    by=c("ID","Veh")    
][
    ,
    .(count = .N),
    by=c("start","stop")
]

#    start   stop count
#1: Area A Area B     2
#2: Area C Area C     1
#3: Area D Area A     2
#4: Area E Area F     1
#5: Area F Area D     1
#6: Area H Area B     1
#7: Area B Area C     1
#8: Area J Area K     1
#9: Area K Area A     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), function(v) {
      if (length(u <- na.omit(unlist(v[-(1:2)]))) == 1) y <- rep(u, 2) else y <- embed(c(u), 2)[, 2:1]
      cbind(v[1:2], `colnames<-`(matrix(y, ncol = 2), c("startArea", "stopArea")), row.names = NULL)
    })
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   ID   Veh startArea stopArea
1   1 Veh 1    Area A   Area B
2   2 Veh 2    Area C   Area C
3   3 Veh 3    Area D   Area A
4   4 Veh 4    Area E   Area F
5   4 Veh 4    Area F   Area D
6   4 Veh 4    Area D   Area A
7   5 Veh 5    Area H   Area B
8   5 Veh 5    Area B   Area C
9   6 Veh 6    Area J   Area K
10  6 Veh 6    Area K   Area A
11  6 Veh 6    Area A   Area B
```